# Why is my dark field photography setup for glass looking different from what a real studio setup would?

Tags: lighting, glass, reflection

I am trying to replicate a dark field photography setup for glass. Similar to this:

[image: Dark field reference]

The final goal is to get a set of clean reflections on a transparent background that I can composite with the separately rendered content for the glass later.

However I get all sorts of transmission and reflection artefacts, that do not appear in real photographs with similar light setups. Especially the middle segment, which is completely without reflections in the reference is bugging me out.

I tried to separate the gloss and transmission rays in the blender compositor, but without success.

I think it is a problem with my glass shader, but I am out of ideas what settings to tweak. The setup looks like this at the moment:

[image: Current Blender setup]

Any help is greatly appreciated!